# Find callback function of custom meta box

Tags: theme-development, metabox

I am reordering the default meta box layout in the following way:

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'move_meta_box');

function move_meta_box(){
    remove_meta_box( 'my-itemsdiv', 'post', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'post', 'side' );
    add_meta_box('my-itemsdiv', __('Something something'), 'X', 'my-item', 'normal', 'high');
    add_meta_box('submitdiv', __( 'Submit item' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', 'my-item', 'normal', 'high' );
}
```

Problem: my-itemsdiv is a custom meta box for the theme and I don't know what callback function to call ("X").

Question: Is there any way I can find out what callback function is used for this meta box? What should I search for? (This theme has quite a bit of code..)

Comment: Simply search the theme code for `add_meta_box`.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, I think they are added programmatically in a minified php file, so I was hoping there was another way...

Comment: What is the theme name to have a look? And what you mean "minified". Obfuscated like Zend Guard?

Answer (score 0):

Please search for `'my-itemsdiv'` or `"my-itemsdiv"` in your theme directory. I'm sure you'll find out the callback function. Because the meta box is registered with the same id. If there's any chance that the meta box is registered via a plugin then find out the plugin first then search in that plugin directory.